React-native-webrtc displays black screen (IOS) in one of the devices
If this is repeated question please let me know for this post to be deleted. I am having an error in react-native-webrtc where I get 3 weird things happening.

All calls get a remote stream of a black screen. I know it has Audio and Video but just see black.

On the second call I get a warning that addIceCandidate failed.

On the third call I just start getting errors saying that it is unable to add an offer because the state is stable


here is my hook implementation
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { RTCPeerConnection, RTCIceCandidate, RTCSessionDescription, mediaDevices, MediaStream } from 'react-native-webrtc';
import { useSharedConnection } from '../context/SignalingContext';
import { CertLocal, CertRequesNoEnct, EasyCall, decryptAESWithJson, encryptJsonWithAES } from './certRequest';

import RNCallKeep from 'react-native-callkeep';

import { useAuthContext } from '../context/authContext';
import { Soundi } from '../screens/videocalls/callingScreen';

const useWebRTCHook = () => {
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null)
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(null)
  const peerConnection = useRef(null);
  const target = useRef(null);
  const tyy = useRef(null);
  const UU = useRef(null);
  const { user, setIsInCall, setCallParams } = useAuthContext()
  const { connection } = useSharedConnection()
  const remoteCandidates = useRef([]);
  const [offerCreated, setOfferCreated] = useState(false);
  var Sound = new Soundi("cbs.mp3")


  const start = async (targetUserId, isVideo = "0", type = "calle",) => {
    tyy.current = type
    if (!offerCreated) {
      let peerConstraints = {
        iceServers: [
          {
            urls: "stun:XXXX",
          },
          {
            urls: "turn:XXXX",
            username: "cw1",
            credential: "XXXX"
          }

        ]

      };

      peerConnection.current = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConstraints);

      const mediaStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
      });
      mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.current.addTrack(track, mediaStream));
      setLocalStream(mediaStream);
      console.log('c-------------------->>>', targetUserId)
      let DataToSend = await encryptJsonWithAES({ Pid: "Patient/" + user.patid.toString(), Uuid: targetUserId }, user.s_aes, user.s_iv)
      let req = await CertLocal(DataToSend, user.token, "", "", "/communications/who-is-calling", user.certificate)
      let res = await decryptAESWithJson(req.replace("\"", ""), user.s_aes, user.s_iv)
      let i = JSON.parse(res)
      target.current = i.target
      UU.current = targetUserId


      if (type === "caller") {
        let offer = await peerConnection.current.createOffer()
        await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(offer)
        await connection.invoke('SendOffer', target.current, offer, peerConnection.current.localDescription, "video");
        setOfferCreated(true);
      }
    }

  };

  async function handleRemoteCandidate(iceCandidate) {
    iceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
    if (peerConnection.current.remoteDescription == null) return remoteCandidates.current.push(iceCandidate);
    return await peerConnection.current.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);

  };

  async function processCandidates() {
    if (remoteCandidates.current.length < 1) { return; };
    remoteCandidates.current.map(candidate => handleRemoteCandidate(candidate));
    remoteCandidates.current = [];
  };




  useEffect(() => {
    if (connection) {
      connection.on('receiveoffer', async (userId, offer, description, type) => {
        if (peerConnection.current && target.current && peerConnection.current.remoteDescription === null && peerConnection.current.localDescription === null) {

          const offerDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(offer)
          await peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(offerDescription)

          const answerDescription = await peerConnection.current.createAnswer();
          await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(answerDescription);

          await connection.invoke('SendAnswer', target.current, answerDescription);

          // Process candidates after setting remote description
          await processCandidates();
        }
      })

      //connection
      connection.on("receiveicecandidate", async (userId, event) => {
        if (peerConnection.current) {
          console.log("receivedIce")
          if (!event.candidate || event.sdpMLineIndex === null || !event.sdpMid) return
          await handleRemoteCandidate(event);
        }
      })


      connection.on('ReceiveAnswer', async (userId, description) => {
        if (peerConnection.current && target.current) {
          const answerDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(description);
          await peerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(answerDescription);

          await processCandidates()
        }
      })

      connection.on('uuidreject', (uuid) => hangleUp(uuid))
    }
    return () => {
      if (connection) {
        connection.off("'ReceiveAnswer")
        connection.off("'receiveoffer")
        connection.off("'SendAnswer")
        connection.off("'receiveicecandidate")
        connection.off("'uuidreject")
      }
    }
  }, [connection])



  useEffect(() => {

    if (peerConnection.current && connection) {


      peerConnection.current.addEventListener('icecandidate', event => SendICe(event));
      peerConnection.current.addEventListener('negotiationneeded', event => NegotiationNeeded(event));
      peerConnection.current.addEventListener('track', event => SetTrack(event));
    }

  }, [connection, peerConnection.current])


  async function SendICe(event) {
    if (!event.candidate) { return; };
    await connection.invoke('SendIceCandidate', target.current, event.candidate);
  }

  async function NegotiationNeeded(event) {
    console.log("negotiationneeded")
    if (tyy && tyy.current === "caller") {
      let offer = await peerConnection.current.createOffer()
      await peerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(offer)
      await connection.invoke('SendOffer', target.current, offer, peerConnection.current.localDescription, "video");
    }
  }
  async function SetTrack(event) {
    console.log("remoteTrack------------------", event.streams)
    setRemoteStream(event.streams[0])
  }


  const hangleUp = async (uuid) => {
    try {


      if (localStream) {
        localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
      }
      setLocalStream(null);
      setRemoteStream(null);
      setIsInCall(false)
      setCallParams(() => null)
      console.log("UU->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", UU.current)
      RNCallKeep.endCall(UU.current);
      await EasyCall(UU.current + ".Pat" + user.patid, "/communications/reject-call")
      setOfferCreated(false)

      peerConnection.current.removeEventListener('icecandidate', event => SendICe(event));
      peerConnection.current.removeEventListener('negotiationneeded', event => NegotiationNeeded(event));
      peerConnection.current.removeEventListener('track', event => SetTrack(event));
      peerConnection.current.close();
      peerConnection.current = null; // Set peerConnection.current to null

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }

  }
  const endCalli = async (id, uuid) => {
    try {

      if (localStream) {
        localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());

      }
      setLocalStream(null);
      setRemoteStream(null);
      
      setOfferCreated(false)
      if(peerConnection.current){
        peerConnection.current.removeEventListener('icecandidate', event => SendICe(event));
        peerConnection.current.removeEventListener('negotiationneeded', event => NegotiationNeeded(event));
        peerConnection.current.removeEventListener('track', event => SetTrack(event));
        peerConnection.current.close();
        peerConnection.current = null; 
      }

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }

  }

  const initiateCall = (targetUserId, userid, isVideoCall, uuid) => {
    connection.invoke('RequestVideoCall', targetUserId, userid.toString(), isVideoCall, uuid, "medux");
  };



  return { initiateCall, start, remoteStream, localStream, endCalli, hangleUp, setLocalStream, setRemoteStream };
};

export default useWebRTCHook;

Can someone help me with what am I doing wrong?
cheers
UPDATE:
I manage to detect that the iceCandidates were not being processed, but now more weird, it works fine in one device, but not in the other. The hook is the same.
